# Кроссбраузерное скругление краев. Возможно на CSS?

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

```
// CSS
.st_all
{
    border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
}
```

Подключая данный стиль, можно скруглить края у картинки/таблицы/итп. Плюс - можно выбрать какой край и на сколько скруглять. Минус - не поддерживает IE.

Может ли кто подсказать более кроссбраузерное решение? Возможно ли обойтись без пакостей в стиле JS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**border-radius**  -  это свойство CSS3. Поэтому, данное свойство поддерживают ВСЕ браузеры, в которых реализована поддержка CSS3. В `IE <= 8` это свойство не поддерживается( тогда еще CSS3 была только в разработке ). GH, Opera и MF всегда впереди, поэтому на их счет можно не беспокоиться. Safari тоже, вроде бы не отстает.

У меня, например, одно лишь свойство **border-radius**( без браузерных предикатов  ) поддерживается во ВСЕХ СОВРЕМЕННЫХ браузерах, включая IE9.

Comment: В IE <= 8...

Comment: Для IE существует [PIE](http://css3pie.com/), который добавляет поддержку `border-radius`, `box-shadow` и т.п.

Answer (score 6):

На Google Code хостится проект Curved Corner с костылем для IE 6, 7, 8. В восьмом точно работает (правда пользователю, возможно, потребуется разрешить активное содержимое, если установлены высокие настройки безопасности), в 6 и 7 не проверял.

**Ссылки:**

- [Страница проекта на Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/)
- [Страница загрузки архива с демкой](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius-demo.zip&can=2&q=)

Answer (score 3):

Вот Вам [**`38 статей о том как закруглить блок.`**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/30019/) И ещё [**`одна.`**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/30286/)

*Итого: ~39 способов закругления блока* **XD**.

Comment: Из них около 9-10 ссылок - битые...итого: 29 способов =)

Answer (score 2):

VML и behaviour — [curved-corner](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/). Для использования сливаем [border-radius.htc](http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc), складываем рядом с CSS и используем следующий код:

```
.my-block {
  /* Для хороших браузеров */
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
  border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
  /* Для плохих IE */
  behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /* учим IE border-radius */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать библиотеку [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)