# В IE 9 не работает border-radius

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Кто знает, как в IE 9 отображать `border-radius`? Во всех браузерах нормально работает, 
кроме IE. Ставил файл border-radius.htc с behavior тоже не работает.

Answer (score 2):

[Уже обсуждалось здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/118746/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css)

Answer (score 0):

Смотри [мануал](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius): там показано, что он должен работать.

Answer (score 0):

Если не работает как на htmlbook.ru, пробуй CSSPie, он тебе точно поможет, на личном опыте знаю, радиусы ставил на IE 7.